# How can I record audio when I play a mp3 file on IOS

Tags: ios, record

I want to play a music at same time record audio. Just like karaoke.
Is this AVAudioEngine can do it or is there have some method to do it.

Comment: Recording and Playing Audio are both different things. There is `AVAudioPlayer` to Play a music, and `AVAudioRecorder` to record. Do some search you will get more information.

Comment: Yes,I think you are right, but I want to record audio  is from mic voice and mp3 track. shall I record voice and  play music ,at the same time save start time and end time at the end of compose them?

Comment: Yes you should be able to record with your voice and mp3 playing, as recording will capture both.